# StackOverflowException in .NET 4

Tags: c#, .net, crash, runtime, stack-overflow

The following code works fine until I upgrade to .NET 4 (x64)

```
namespace CrashME
{
    class Program
    {
        private static volatile bool testCrash = false;
        private static void Crash()
        {
            try
            {
            }
            finally
            {
                HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert("xxx", testCrash);
            }

        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Crash();
            // Works on .NET 3.5 , crash on .NET 4
        }
    }
}
```

Did I just uncover a runtime bug, or is there some issue with my usage?

Comment: +1 for __StackOverflow__Exception :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would appear to be a bug in the CLR - you should report it to Microsoft.

Note that the `StackOverflowException` occurs *as* the CLR attempts to execute the  `Crash`, not *during* the execution of the `Crash` method - the program in fact never enters the method.  This would appear to indicate that this is some low-level failure in the CLR.  (Also note that the thrown exception also has no stack trace).

This exception is incredibly specific to this situation - changing any one of a number of things fixes this, for example the following code works fine:

```
private static void Crash()
{
    bool testCrash2 = testCrash;
    try { }
    finally
    {
        HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert("xxx", testCrash2);
    }
}
```

I would recommend that you report this to Microsoft, but attempt to work around the issue by tweaking your code in the meantime.

Comment: Ok, the CLR team have been notified so we should see a fix for this at some point

Answer (score 3):

I can reproduce it on an x86 machine. The following code also fails:

```
        try
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            var foo = new List<object>();
            foo.Add(testCrash);
        }
```

However, the following code succeeds:

```
        try
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            var foo = new List<bool>();
            foo.Add(testCrash);
        }
```

I thought it might have something to do with the boxing of volatile fields within the finally block, but then I tried the following (which also fails):

```
        try
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            bool[] foo = new bool[1];
            foo[0] = testCrash;
        }
```

Very interesting problem...